How does one fade particles by their proximety?
I've instanced particles in a volume with geometry nodes, but I'd like their distance to fade as they get far away from each other. Is there a way to achieve this is a simple way? Do I have to index all the points, index the materials, and then how do I check the distance comparison for each of them? Is there an easier way?

It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question. Have you tried this tutorial? https://youtu.be/pcthKcjc2aY or https://blenderartists.org/t/procedural-firework-with-geometry-nodes-in-blender-tutorial/1409586

What does this mean, you'd like "their distance to fade away as they get far away from each other"? The distance will not "fade", it will grow larger. That's what happens when things move away from each other.

Could it be the "size" instead of the "distance" ? Particules far away (i.e. at large distance) from any other particules are "small" ; particules close to other particules (i.e.  at small distance) are "big" ?
